# Font with weight between HelveticaNeue and HelveticaNeue-Light or way to change weight of HelveticaNeue

Tags: ios, fonts, uikeyboard, typography, uifontweighttrait

I am trying to mimic as closely as possible iOS default system  keyboard's font. Apparently, the family is `HelveticaNeue` but the weight is neither `HelveticaNeue-Light` (too light) nor `HelveticaNeue` (too heavy).

My research shows that default system iOS keyboard  uses something called  [Dynamic Type with Optical scaling](http://typographica.org/on-typography/beyond-helvetica-the-real-story-behind-fonts-in-ios-7/). Is this available to third party developers (outside Apple)? If not, how can I mimic default keyboard's Helvetica Neue weight?

Comment: I have the same trouble with San Francisco font, and till now there is no solution.